# 64 bit application taking more memory on same load

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, 64-bit, console-application

in this vast world of development i'm still a newbie and keep learning stuff,recently whilst monitoring a service i noticed an abrupt behavior.

I have a simulation tool which generates load on my application. If i deploy my application as 32-bit application then the application hardly consumes 300MB on full load. However if it deploy the console application as a 64-Bit application, it starts consuming resources hungrily and at same load level as 32-bit application, it consumes minimum of 900MB in memory.

Can anyone explain what is happening with the application? any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: That shouldn't surprise you - pointers and instructions are x2 bigger, the modules themselves are bigger (core dll's are larger on their 64 bit version), and that's just a partial list :)

Comment: @shay__ do you have an article to help my case out?

Comment: You can start here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526984/bit-vs-bit-memory . If you google it, you will find many more resources.

Comment: @shay__: No, they are not two times bigger (100% + 200% => 300%), but (some of them) 100% bigger (100% + 100% => 200%) - which makes it strange that the result is actually thrice as big.

Answer (score 1):

The primary change between 64 bit and 32 bit is the width of the address field, which has increased to 8 bytes (64 bits) from 4 bytes(32 bits). So, evidently, more the number of references/objects in your application, more is the memory consumption in 64 bit. Read more about 32 bit vs 64 bits [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526984/bit-vs-bit-memory).

Having said that, it's bit suspicious that it consumes 3 times more memory in 64 bit version. I would get a proper memory profiler and test if your application has any memory leaks. If there are no memory leaks, there is nothing much to be worry about memory consumption differences in 32 bit and 64 bit.